# Is there list of the least to most dangerous transport types sorted, not by journey, person or distance, but by TIME per person?

Tags: public-transport, safety

Whenever I see "planes are safer than driving by car", it's always based under the metric of by "miles travelled per crash", or "journeys per crash" based. The latter might be bad because it may not account for that we make far fewer trips on a plane than a car, and also may discount that multiple people may die if the plane crashes. Even if we put those in, people have different transport requirements and may drive or fly near or far. It's a crude metric overall.

"Miles travelled per crash" may also be misleading due to the multiple people on board a plane, and even if you use per capita (person), I'd argue that many people intuitively prefer to go by time instead of miles when travelling, at least on some occasions. We tend to ignore how far the destination is, and instead just look at how long we're spending on the mode of transport.

So to reiterate the title, is there a list of the least to most dangerous forms of transport where we take into account the time spent upon that vehicle, per person?

Comment: I think that it is usually deaths per passenger mile.  So, a plane crash won't be equivalent to a single car crash but hundreds of car crashes.

Comment: Also, the difference between plane and train safety is so great that planes will come out better in either measure.  Consider trains which are also much safer than cars.

Comment: In the previous comment, it should have been "between plane and CAR safety".

Comment: Note that if you want to chose the safest option between different modes of transport you generally pick between options that bring you from some point A to some point B. To meaningfully compare them you should look at deaths per passenger mile not at deaths per hour in transport. There is a good reason deaths per passenger mile is the standard for measuring this, it is the scale that allows you to make useful comparisons.

Comment: Remembering that take off and landing are by far the most dangerous parts of air travel, I don't see how comparing a 14 hour flight (with one take off/landing) to 14 hours of driving (where each passing moment is getting more dangerous as I'm growing more tired toward the end) is in any way, shape, or form a valid comparison.

Comment: @quarague: Different transport modes can and should be optimized for different metrics. Elevators, for example, are optimized for the per-journey metric, because most people will take many extremely short rides in an elevator rather than one very long ride.

Comment: @Kevin I only use an elevator when it's a very long ride, otherwise I run less than 3 floors, or walk.

Comment: @WeatherVane: 3 floors is 30 ft (~10 m). Nobody drives a car 30 ft.

Comment: @Kevin 3 floors isn't a long ride, as mentioned I run that far then walk. Many people drive to the corner shop when it is only short walk.

Comment: @WeatherVane: My point is that your stated minimum threshold for using an elevator (30 ft) is *much much* shorter than most people's minimum threshold for using almost any other mode of transportation that is not walking or perhaps cycling.

Comment: @Kevin that's not my minimum threshold. 3 floor is my *running* threshold, then I walk.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Well, if you meant that, you shouldn't have said "**less than** 3 floors."

Comment: @Kevin: *otherwise I run less than 3 floors, or walk.* I run three floors. Then I walk.

Comment: @quarague The thing is that in _engineering_, risk is usually calculated per operating hour. For example, aircraft certification requires no more than 1 crater per 10^9 flight hours (FAA AC 25.1309-1). On cars, ASIL (ISO 26262) is also failures per hour, e.g. ASIL D, the probability your airbags randomly deploy is less than 10^-8/hr. Therefore, you have to do a translation when comparing the relative risk where substitution can occur. That is, to decide whether you fly or drive, you translate the risks into per-km.

Comment: @FreeMan A 14-hour drive doesn't necessarily have to be completed all at once.  There's also the possibility that the flight crew is overtired. Further, suppose I'm planning a weekend getaway, deciding between various destinations, some of which I would drive to, some I would take a train or bus to, and others I would fly to -- the last being much farther away -- but in every case I am allowing no more than three hours travel time because, well, it's a weekend getaway.  If I were to include risk of accident or death in my decision, statistics based on time would be helpful.

Comment: I think that in case of surface travel the location should be taken in account. Bus travel might come out very safe in some countries, but might be much less safe in other countries.

Comment: You could take statistics on deaths per passenger mile, and multiply them by some reasonable estimate of the average speed of that transport type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found another source for risk by hour of travel, from Turbli.

[**The Safest Transport Modes, Ranked by Statistics From 10 Years of Data**](https://turbli.com/blog/the-safest-transport-modes-ranked-by-statistics-from-10-years-of-data/).

> The analysis is done for the US only, using the data provided by the [Bureau of Transportation Statistics (BTS)](https://www.bts.gov/).

It includes risk by absolute fatalities, by passenger mile, and –

> **Fatalities by passenger hours**
>
> [image]

The chart isn't sorted by risk, but you can see it is broadly similar to the data I showed in another answer. However the chart is visually distorted because the length of each bar isn't proportional to its statistic.

The linked article has a lengthy discussion about travel risk. It mentions these sources:

> US Bureau of Transportation Statistics. [National Transportation Statistics](https://www.bts.gov/product/national-transportation-statistics?keys=&field_topic_target_id=All).
> US Federal Transit Administration. [Annual National Transit Summaries and Trends](https://www.transit.dot.gov/ntd/annual-national-transit-summaries-and-trends).
> Savage I., 2013. [Comparing the fatality risks in United States transportation across modes and over time](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0739885912002156). Research in Transportation Economics, 43, 9-22.

---

It seems that my earlier answer used a UK data set and this one uses a US data set.
It can be seen that bus, rail, car and motorcycle are in the same sequence of risk.

But a significant difference is the US data making **3 categories** for air travel.

- "scheduled flight with more than 10 passengers" is safer than by bus.
- "scheduled flight with less than 10 passengers" is worse than by car.
- "private plane" is *much* worse, more than half the risk of a motorbike.

The UK data presumably averages all three categories, but "scheduled flight with more than 10 passengers" is what most people travelling will think of by "flying".

Comment: Looks like the chart is in log scale. I guess its author didn't find it necessary to add any tick marks to make this clear.

Comment: Compare to the fatality rate of "life": 1 death per 80 years of life gives about 1,427 fatalities per billion hours. Only private planes & motorcycles are more dangerous, per hour, than just living.

Comment: @RalphJ You need to use that number with relative travel times, so you can say taking the train from A to B does or does not reduce your life expectancy more than taking a bus.

Comment: @Anyon Yeah, the chart vastly downplays how dangerous motorcycles are. They only "look" twice as dangerous as cars based on bar area.

Comment: @Anyon Just for interests sake, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM5rc.png) is the graph reproduced to show log vs linear scale. You'll have to forgive the log scale showing ticks of 5's rather than 10s, quirk of Excel.

Comment: *bus, rail, car and motorcycle are in the same sequence of risk* => seems like bus and rail are 10x safer than car and car is 50x safer than motorcycle?

Comment: @JonathanReez yes: bus, rail, car and motorbike are in the same sequence in both data sets. Bus is safest, then rail, next comes car and motorbike is last in both lists.

Comment: OP here, and my first response. Thanks a ton for both the answers! Which one should I tick do you think? I notice car is 4x safer per hour than plane in this chart (120 vs 445), but in your previous answer, it's about the reverse where plane is 4x safer than car (30.8 vs 130). Any ideas why this might be the case? Do you think it's because the first answer takes into account commercial planes too and averages in a biased way? I presume both are pure per capita.

Comment: They are per person per travel time. As mentioned in this answer, I think the difference for air travel is that the US data is subdivided, showing that mass-transit air travel is relatively safe. For long haul, it's pretty much Hobson's Choice anyway, unless you have a fear of flying, want the adventure, or love Shank's Pony. Which one to tick? It doesn't really matter. This answer could have been an extension to my other answer, and builds on it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Since it's per capita, I'm still not sure why the "less than 10 passengers" category should be worse than less than the "more than 10 passengers" category.

Comment: Because the smaller planes are more likely to crash, and the private planes even more so (per passenger-hour)? You asked if there are any statistics, and I have provided two independent sets. I didn't compile them, so my guesses are as good as yours.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Ah that makes sense. I presumed the "less than 10 passengers" category was on the same size plane, but if it's smaller, then that carries risk independent of the number of people on the plane. I do have one more question though: Why do they claim the flight with "more than 10 passengers" category is safer than the bus category, when the chart shows the commuter plane (445) to be 100x less safe than the Bus category (3) ? I imagine that "more than 10 passengers" roughly correlates to "commuter plane".

Comment: I think it relates to the size of the plane, not the actual number of passengers on board. The three categories being broadly mass transit (inter-city, say), small capacity regular services (say, island-hoppers), and private ownership (bikers with wings).

Comment: @DanW There's a minor typo in the chart, footnote 4 should read in parenthesis 14 CFR 121 and 5 should read 14 CFR 135. They're actually very specific, "Part 121" refers to the very strict rules airlines run under, and "Part 135" refers to other commercial air carriers. Major differences include a special pilot's license for Part 121 that requires more flying time, and Part 121 requires at least 2 engines, where Part 135 planes can have one.

Comment: Okay, even with the above info, I'm still at a loss why in this answer, the commuter plane category (which would presumably account for the vast majority of people flying generally) is about 4x more dangerous than car per hour per person, whilst in the other answer, it's the other way around. If anyone can explain the discrepancy, that would be appreciated.

Comment: In the first answer with UK data, you should presume that the single category for air is for all types of air travel. It has not been separated into three categories, so it isn't directly comparable with any one category in the US data.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I considered that, but since commuter passenger planes would make up the vast number of people flying, I assumed the stats from that would drown out the the other plane types to make up that final average figure of 30.8 (speaking for the UK data set).

Comment: There may well be different usage of air travel in UK. It's a small country, and most air commuting isn't done in < 10 seater aircraft. Although there are smaller aircraft serving the Scottish Isles, that's not really commuter territory. The vast majority of air travel in the UK is dosmetic between the major cities, or international.

Answer (score 30):

[This page from REStARTS](https://www.fp7-restarts.eu/index.php/home/root/state-of-the-art/objectives/2012-02-15-11-58-37/75-book-video/how-a-plane-can-fly-assuring-safety/156-the-risk-of-travel.html) has a table (**emphasis** original):

> **7. The risk of travel**
>
> There are three possible ways of quoting transport risk; in terms of distance travelled, number of journeys or time of travel. Interested parties tend to choose the form of presentation that suits their own purposes.
>
> The air transport industry, for example, will almost always choose a per km basis, which is optimum for them, as most fatalities occur on landing and take-off, while the distances are large. Land based transport organisations, in contrast, will tend to select fatalities per number of journeys or hours of travel, since the risks are uniformly spread. Thus both are able to demonstrate that theirs is the safest form of transport. The actual statistics are given below (taken from an article by Roger Ford in Modern Railways, Oct 2000 and based on a DETR survey). They record the number of fatalities per **billion km, billion journeys** or **billion hours** of travel.
>
> | km | journeys | hours |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **Air 0.05** | Bus 4.3 | Bus 11.1 |
> | Bus 0.4 | Rail 20 | Rail 30 |
> | Rail 0.6 | Van 20 | **Air 30.8** |
> | Van 1.2 | Car 40 | Water 50 |
> | Water 2.6 | Foot 40 | Van 60 |
> | Car 3.1 | Water 90 | Car 130 |
> | Pedal cycle 44.6 | **Air 117** | Foot 220 |
> | Foot 54.2 | Pedal cycle 170 | Pedal cycle 550 |
> | Motorcycle 108.9 | Motorcycle 1,640 | Motorcycle 4,840 |

So if you are concerned about risk: **bus** is safest.

In the first column (by km) **air** is safest, and significantly less safe in the other columns. Even though **bus** isn't a viable alternative for those long distance flights it is still second. Apart from that, **bus** is safer than all other modes of transport, whatever way the stats are presented, and **rail** comes next.

---

Regarding the original sources, I looked through the many pages of articles by Roger Ford in Modern Railways, and there were 3 in October 2022, the most likely being [Informed Sources: Constraints needed for accident investigation closures](https://www.modernrailways.com/article/informed-sources-constraints-needed-accident-investigation-closures) but the site needs a subscription to read the article. I also searched on Department of the Environment, Transport and the Regions (DETR) at [The National Archives](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/) but found nothing for "travel safety air bus train".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149377/discussion-on-answer-by-weather-vane-is-there-list-of-the-least-to-most-dangerou); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, the article by Roger Ford was in 2000, but the *Modern Railways* online archive only seems to go back to 2020.

Comment: (Chat room is closed and nobody there made this argument anyway.) I am not sure how you can arrive at the summary "So if you are concerned about risk: bus is safest.". Very clearly, **if you are concerned about risk *you should fly*** because it is about **an order of magnitude safer.** I say this so confidently because fatalities/journey and fatalities/hour compare apples with pears (average trip size is very different, and speed is very different). If you are facing a *specific trip* the only thing that counts is the risk for *that trip* which is solely determined by distance.

Comment: As an example, if you plan a trip around the world, walking (which would take years) would be much much riskier than flying which would take about two or three days. That is true even if *risk per journey* is not very good for planes. Well, yes, because those trips are much longer. Fore a specific risk, you must look at the specific trip. Yes, if you fly between continents, your risk is higher than when you walk to the grocer. That is what is reflected in the journey column but it is not what should inform your decision concerning a specific trip.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the 'by km' column shows that air is safest from that point of view, but you won't be doing long journeys by bus anyway. **Bus is at the top of the 'per journey' and 'per hour' columns.** That's why I said it was safest. You've cherry-picked a quite unusual journey.

Comment: The bus from Berlin to Milano takes 16 hours. The flight takes 1.6 hours. Yes, the risk *per hour* is only 1/3 for the bus but the trip takes 10 times as long, making it overall 3 times riskier. What is so hard to understand about that? Sure, 1.6 hours on the bus are pretty safe, they just don't get you there. To minimize risk, you have to ply.

Comment: It is safer per journey. But generally, you'd go by the most convenient or desirable means anyway.

Comment: **It is not safer per specific journey,** which is the choice one faces in reality. *Of course* it is much safer per (journey typical for each mode of transportation): How long is your typical bus ride?? For me it's 20 minutes/5 kilometers. No wonder it's safer than my typical plane trip which will take me (actually!) from Berlin to Houston tomorrow. That's the apples and pears. If you want to play it safe, do not travel large distances. But if you must, take the plane.

Comment: The question was not about a specific journey, and they were not my statistics. The OP presumably wants to go the safest way, and that chart is what was available. The safest method, is the one that you *feel* safest on.

Comment: I do not doubt the table values. I reject your *interpretation* of it, the conclusion you draw, which is plain wrong. And with all due respect: "The safest method, is the one that you feel safest on" is just intellectually poor.

Comment: I wrote that because, as you say, exact comparisons are difficult. I fail to see why you reject the idea that the means with the lowset risk shown, is not the lowest risk. That's all I have to say, but please re-read the answer, not just the table, which explains why the 'per journey' is very relevant.